# Convert basic CSS to Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I got this normal css and want to convert to TailwinCSS. How do I convert this css code to TailwindCSS?

```
.status {padding: 5px;border-radius: 5px;&.Approved {color: green;background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.151);}&.Pending {color: goldenrod;background-color: rgba(189, 189, 3, 0.103);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Arbitrary variants to select child elements with specific class names.

```
<div class="rounded-[5px] p-[5px] [&_.Approved]:bg-green-200 [&_.Pending]:bg-slate-100 [&_.Pending]:text-yellow-400">
  <div class="Approved"></div>
  <div class="Pending"></div>
</div>
```

Reference - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants